# "tmx" (tmux) erroneously connects to existing session because of prefix matching

Tags: tmux

I used "tmx" to create a tmux session called "foos" and now I want to create a new session called "foo", where the latter is a prefix of the former. But tmux connects me to the existing session instead.

I would like to create the specified session directly. Even better, I'd like to switch "tmx" away from prefix matching and to exact matching when working with sessions in all contexts.

My "tmx" script has a bunch of stuff in it, but I think the relevant part is:

```
  if tmux has-session -t "${name}" &> /dev/null; then
    exec env SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${d}/${s}" ${f} tmux "${args[@]}" attach-session -t "${name}"
  else
    exec env SSH_AUTH_SOCK="${d}/${s}" ${f} tmux "${args[@]}" new-session -s "${name}"
  fi
```

Comment: What is the question? This is a questions and answers site. Also, it might be beneficial for the sake of clarity to replace "tmx" in the OP with "my custom script", or something like that.

Comment: "I want to create a new session called "foo", where the latter is a prefix of the former. But tmux connects me to the existing session instead." That means the question is: "how do I make it do what I want?" Kamil got it and answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 1 tmux`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#COMMANDS):

> `target-session` is tried as, in order:
>
> 1. A session ID prefixed with a `$`.
> 2. An exact name of a session (as listed by the `list-sessions` command).
> 3. The start of a session name, for example `mysess` would match a session named `mysession`.
> 4. An `fnmatch(3)` pattern which is matched against the session name.

So it is by design: if there is no exact match, less exact matching kicks in. Unless…

> If the session name is prefixed with an `=`, only an exact match is accepted (so `=mysess` will only match exactly `mysess`, not `mysession`).

Solution: use `-t "=${name}"` where appropriate.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: It works (it suppresses the prefix match) but it does create sessions with the equal sign in them. Sigh.

Comment: @MihaiDanila What do you mean? You do not create a session with `-t "=${name}"`, you do it with `new-session -s "${name}"` and this is the part that did and does work fine as it is.

Comment: I only create sessions with "tmx <session name>" straight from the shell and so I tried "tmx =<session name>". I don't think I'd like to type "new-session" all the time, I'd rather live with the occasional prefix issue than switch to that. :)

Comment: @MihaiDanila Sigh… Inside your script keep using `new-session -s "${name}"`, so there is no `=` *there*; but use `-t "=${name}"` elsewhere, so matching is exact.

Comment: "tmx" comes preinstalled in /usr/bin, I may not be able to modify it, or at least not in a persistent way, since it's managed by my employer. I think I just need to stop using "tmx" or build my own override to it, as the problem seems to be in the script itself, as you say.

Comment: @MihaiDanila Report the bug to whoever maintains the script. Include a link to this answer maybe.